# Branching Logic on custom list with redirection - 3 scenarios (screenshots)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, web-part, custom-list

I´m struggling with something that probably isn´t that hard. I am a beginner in sharepoint, sorry if the question is too basic.

So, the situation and scenarios are the following: 
I have this form (as custom list) to collect information from workers about accidents. At the end, they have the option to offer a suggestion to prevent this accident.

1) Perfect scenario:
They select "Ja" (yes), click on Ok to Submit and get redirected to the link presented there (which wouldn´t need to be there in this scenario) and then they would provide their input in this other platform of our company.

2) Not-that-bad scenario:
They select Ja, the field "Link" appears (as result from branching logic) and they click on the link on the right side and a new tab opens.

3) Worst-scenario:
They click on the link and it opens on a new tab.

[image: Screenshoot one]

Could anyone give me some input here? PS1: Very beginner level here, sorry if the question is too basic.
PS2: SharePoint 2007

Here is a screenshoot of my code

[image: code]

Thanks a lot!